# Detecting the PC is running on UPS Power and shutdown Computer

Tags: bash, hardware

I'm downloading huge sums of data at night and my PC in running through a UPS. Is there any way I can detect a power failure and command my PC to shut down automatically? Because I work at night, and there's no one to switch off the PC, it would be really helpful if anyone could help. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this on Linux? Which distro? I would imagine that the power management features in the kernel generate an event in response to this. Google for ACPI and your distro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**IMPORTANT:** The scripts presented below will cause the system to shutdown whenever the network is down, so use them at your own risk!

A not so elegant way of doing what you want, if you have a network host (e.g. your router) that responds to ICMP echo requests and is not powered by the UPS (or at least the networking equipment is not powered by the UPS), would be to ping that host every few seconds and if it's down then shutdown the PC:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
  ping -c 1 -w 5 192.168.0.1 &> /dev/null
  if [  $? -gt 0  ]; then
    shutdown -hP now
    break
  fi
  sleep 10s
done
```

You will have to change 192.168.0.1 to the IP address of the network host you want to ping.

You will also have to make the script executable with `chmod +x <script_name>` and place a call to it in `/etc/rc.local` (do not forget to append a `&` to make it run in the background) which will run the script as root on boot.

For completeness' sake, if the PC was running Windows XP one could use the following batch file:

```
:loop
ping -n 1 -w 5000 192.168.0.1
if not %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    shutdown -s
    goto end
)
sleep 10
goto loop
:end
```

Note that the Windows batch file requires the `sleep` command which can be installed as part of the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools package ([available as a free download from Microsoft's site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657))

Comment: I've tried this also, works well - Find a complete script, with a number of variables, at this gist: https://gist.github.com/thanosa75/d0eb2a30cf280948c0155fcc17b0d4be

Answer (score 0):

If it's an APC and it has a data port you can use PowerChute. It's a java-based GUI (which could be a problem if this is your server) that does exactly what you are requesting.

Comment: no man this is a prolink ups. i did c what u mentioned in the net. and yes it does what i want. but cause this is another brand, i need some other way..thanks anyway..:)